# Path-finding an unexplored maze

Tags: search, graph, depth-first-search, path-finding, a-star

I have a tile-based maze. In the beginning I am aware of my coordinates, the coordinates of the target tile and at each point I can tell which of the four adjacent tiles I can move onto. This means that I have to explore the maze as I attempt to solve it to learn more about it.

What would be an appropriate algorithm to solve this graph taking into account the maze-has-to-be-explored twist?

Comment: There are many different maze solving algorithms. [This wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maze_solving_algorithm) highlights a few

Comment: I've struggled to find any resources that take into consideration a maze that is yet to be explored.

Comment: See this answer about the D* algorithm on gamedev.stackexchange  http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/54457/20360

Comment: If it's a perfect maze, you can just use the right-hand rule. Just remove any locations you've already seen from the solution if you visit them twice (backtracking).

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend looking into A* algorithm, Dijkstra's algorithm, D* algorithm, depth first search and breadth first search.. Jump-point-search.

A good demo is found here:

http://qiao.github.io/PathFinding.js/visual/

if you need any help on implementation just ask, I primarily do C++ but also Java, c# and python.

you don't need to have any knowledge about the 'maze/grid' prior to pathfinding as you will be checking only immediate neighbours.

B C C

B A C

C C B

here where A = Agent, B = Blocked and C = Clear..

if you were using an A* implementation you would have two lists:

Open: add all nodes you encounter which are movable (in my example C are movable nodes).

Closed: One you decide on next move add the node to Closed list.

Cost is evaluated by F(G + H)

G = actual cost (accumulates when you add each move) e.g. +10 for a vertical/horizontal move and +15 for a diagonal.

H = is your heuristic, generally you use something like the Manhattan distance which is the distance from Agent A to destination D taking only Horizontal and Vertical movement into consideration.

So as you can see.. you have no need to know the map specifics.